# QTimer won't start when passing a variable

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I have a QTimer object that kicks off a function every second.  The timer runs correctly if I do the following

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    // Set a Qtimer to update the OSD display every 1 second
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(print()));
    timer->start(1000);
}

void MainWindow::print() 
{
    printf("hello world\n");
}
```

But I want to pass a variable to *print()*.  But when I do this, I never see my print statement.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    // Set a Qtimer to update the OSD display every 1 second
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);    
    int val = 42;
    // Now pass val to print()
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(print(val)));
    timer->start(1000);
}

void MainWindow::print(int val) 
{
    // I never see my print statement
    printf("hello world, val=%d\n", val);
}
```

header.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();

    public slots:
        void print(int val);
```

Why does this not work?  What can I do to pass a variable into *print()* using QTimer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(print(val)));
```

Qt signal/slot connections don't work that way.  The text within the SIGNAL() and SLOT() macros has to be the signature of the signal/slot method, verbatim; you can't put variables or other non-method-signature text there.

If you look at your program's stdout while it runs, you'll see an error message printed by connect() telling you that it can't find any slot-method named print(val).

If you want to provide a separate value for your slot, you could either make val a member-variable of your class, and have print() look at the member variable instead of an argument, or you could use an intermediary slot, like this:

```
public slots:
   void print(int val); 
   void print42() {print(val);}
```

... and then connect your signal to SLOT(print42()) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer.  I figured it was something to do with the signature, but I didn't notice the error message to stdout until now.  I will mark this as correct as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: Just to extend on this answer, there is a class called QSignalMapper which allows you to create simple mappings between objects for this very purpose (i.e. to provide actual values as an argument to some slot function when a signal with no parameters is emitted).